How to put a circle above a letter
In the name "Matušů-Nečasová",what is the code for "ů".I need to write the name in the reference, not in the equation enviroment.

Thanks for answering my question. I was using the template given by the press. It used the ctex package. It used LaTex to generate the dvi file and then use dvi2pdf to generate the pdf file. I used "\bibitem{}" to add a reference. The .tex file was encoded by GBK, It seems that I can not directly input "ů" in the .tex file. But "\r{u}" really worked

Welcome to TeX SE. Have you looked on detexify?

Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and just type (or copy-paste) the character as is into the source. You say "reference": Do you use some bibliography tool (such as biber) and, if yes, which one? Please tell us more about your set-up. With PDFLaTeX, you can try \r{u}.

@JasperHabicht You can also just type or copy-paste for pdfLaTeX, too ;). On Linux, you can enter the character directly if you have configured a compose key, even if your keyboard configuration doesn't include the character directly, with <compose>ou, for example. (This is a three key sequence - not a combination.)

If this is in a .bib entry and you're using Biblatex with Biber, don't use \r{u} for pdfLaTeX. Only Unicode characters work without problems in my experience (but I don't know why, so maybe I'm doing something wrong).

@cfr You're absolutely right. I should have phrased this differently. Anyways, it is the "traditional" way to input ů and might be of some use depending on the setup of the OP.
